# Vercel deployment issue: Build and Development Settings defined in Project Settings will not apply due to 'builds' existing in configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, vercel

I'm encountering a persistent warning in my Vercel deployments, and I need some assistance in resolving it. The warning message is as follows:
[Vercel warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIDCJ.png)

I've reviewed the provided link, but I'm still unsure how to properly configure my Vercel project settings and vercel.json file to eliminate this warning and ensure that the Build and Development Settings are applied correctly.

Here's a snippet of my vercel.json file:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "vercel-build.sh",
        "use": "@vercel/ruby"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "env": {
      "RUBY_ENV": "production"
    }
}
```

And here's a screenshot of my Vercel Project Settings and Environment Variables page:
[Vercel project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbcsn.png)
[Vercel environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whbLN.png)

I would appreciate any insights on how to properly structure the vercel.json file and configure the project settings on the Vercel dashboard to avoid this warning. Additionally, if there are any best practices or examples related to the @vercel/ruby build, that information would be valuable.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!